# how to check if an object is a certain type in python

Tags: python, object, methods, types, isinstance

Im trying to make a method that checks if the object will be of a faculty type based from the faculty class. This is the code but im getting a syntax error?

```
def addFaculty(self, f_obj):
        if f_obj isinstance(f_obj, Faculty):
            return True
        else:
            self.directory.append(f_obj)
```

Comment: `if f_obj isinstance`: Why do you have `f_obj` before `ininstance`? That's invalid syntax. You're giving that object to `isinstance` as an argument in the `()`.

Comment: `if isinstance(f_obj, Faculty):` - put the variable in the function call.

Comment: Thank yall very Much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def addFaculty(self, f_obj): 
    return isinstance(f_obj, Faculty)
```

or:

```
def addFaculty(self, f_obj):
    return type(f_obj) is Faculty
```

Comment: Just making it worse. The second form doesn't account for subclasses.

Comment: ahh yeah forgot about the append part, but really curious about the subclass thing tho.

Comment: tho i think it will depend on the use case o the checking if he wants that class or a sub or just that class

Comment: Suppose someone creates `class TemporaryFaculty(Faculty)` - the test would fail. But that's fundamental to OOP polymorphism. A subclass should be able to take the place of its parent.

Comment: @tdelaney then what if the desired output is to check if and only if the object is an instance to that class nd not one of it's children?

Comment: That would be extremely uncommon - such an exceptional requirement would need to be noted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Class name not acceptable to use from method scope.
 For this purposes use `__class__` attr of obj `self`.

```
def addFaculty(self, f_obj): 
    if isinstance(f_obj, self.__class__): 
        return True 
    else: 
        self.directory.append(f_obj)
```

Comment: No, on multiple levels. You still have the syntax error and the signature is `isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple, /)`

Comment: Of cource, becouse i copied your (@tdelaney) code fully. Syntax error with using `isinstance` func. Signature of which is `def isinstance (obj, class_or_tuple, /) -> bool:`. Annotation is important. If constraction mention to use bool value to branch code, but u place to values next to each other `<class "Faculty"> bool`. This not matching any regular expression that use python interpriter in this context

Comment: But why test against `self.__class__` when you want to test against `Faculty`? It would only work if this is another method of the `Faculty` class and would break with a subclass of `Faculty`. Just use `Faculty`.

Comment: @tdelaney, you right. But if you want to store all subclasses there is another way. It is using `__init_subclass__` method.

Comment: That is going even further afield. Why would you want custom class cresation to I guess add some facility to do what `isinstance(obj, class)` already does? You say _Class name not acceptable to use from method scope_ and that just isn't true.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative way to implement simular feature is to use `__init_subclass__` method

```
class Faculty:
    dictionary= {}
    def __init_subclass__ (cls, **kwargs): 
        Faculty.dictionary[cls.__name__] = cls
 
class New(Faculty):
    pass

print(Faculty.dictionary)
```

Output: `{'New': (class '__main__.New')}`

Comment: Why would anybody do this? This would not handle like-named classes in other modules, complex inheritance graphs or mixins. `isinstance(f_obj, Faculty)` is the right way to do this.

Comment: @tdelaney, for example, interface to iterate over classmethod only classes.

Comment: The task is to check object type.